# weblogic 12c node manager inactive

Tags: weblogic

I am trying to start the node manager on Weblogic12c, but it is throwing me this error:

<Feb 23, 2017 3:59:33 AM EST>  
java.io.IOException: The server is unable to create a server socket for listening. The address omcsebsorc might be incorrect or another process is using port 5,556: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

How should I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

Some other process is listening at the ip/port you specified for nodemanager (omcsebsorc:5556). Try to find out which process it is with

```
netstat -tulpen | grep 5556
```

In the last column you can see the name an the PID of the listening process (only if you run this command as root or the process-owner).
If this process is not the nodemgr process, find out if you need this process. If not, kill it and try to start your nodemgr. If you need it, you can set another port for nodemgr in you nodemanager.properties (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/confignodemgr.html#1143157)

If it is a nodemgr - process, you have already running one. Try to connect to your Adminserver and check if the nodemgr is running.